# Join in datamapper in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join, datamapper, codeigniter-datamapper

How to Create **INNER JOIN** query in datamapper in codeigniter?

`Country : id(int) | Name(varchar)`

`User : id(int) | name(varchar) | country_id(int)`

**Required Query**
`SELECT * FROM User u INNER JOIN Country c ON(c.id = u.country_id) WHERE u.name LIKE %abcd%`

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the properties in you Model accordingly:

```
class User extends DataMapper {

    var $has_one = array("country");

    function __construct($id = NULL)
    {
        parent::__construct($id);
    }
}

class Country extends DataMapper {
    var $has_many = array("user");

    function __construct($id = NULL)
    {
        parent::__construct($id);
    }
}
```

[Official Doc](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/settingrelations.html)

You then can query related models like this:

```
$u = new User();
$u->like_related_country('name', 'abc')->get();
```

You can find all query-options [here](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html#_related_model)

Comment: How to create inner join relation in datamapper?

Comment: The trick about ORMapper are that you do not have to write joins most of the time, because the relationships take care for that.

Comment: Please tell how to create relation for this query

Comment: It is stated in the code above and more is found when you follow the link. You have to do some work yourself, StackOverflow is not here to provide a full code for you.